# Two questions about first order theories having only finite models.

Tags: logic

Let T be a consistent theory formalized in the first order predicate calculus, all of whose models are finite and have cardinal numbers less than some positive integer n(T). Is T necessarily decidable? By Lindenbaum's theorem, T has-at least one-consistent and complete extension, T*. Does there always exist such a T* having only finite models that cannot be arbitrarily large?

Comment: If $T$ has completions with arbitrarily large models, then $T$ has arbitrarily large models, therefore it has an infinite model.

Comment: If $T$ has a finite model, then the theory of that model is a consistent and complete extension of $T$ having only finite models that cannot be arbitrarily large.

Comment: For the decidability question, are you assuming that the theory has a finite number of non-logical symbols? Otherwise, I think you can have an undecidable theory having only one-element models.

Comment: Isn't every model of $T^*$ also a model of $T$, and thus every model of $T^*$ is no larger than $n(T)$?

Comment: @bof: yes, that is certainly the case, if you were asking whether it is possible. We can make a computably axiomatized theory with one constant symbol and an infinite sequence of unary relation symbols, so that every model of the theory has only one element, and so there is no computable model of the theory (which means in particular that the theory is not decidable).

Comment: The easiest example I know is to take two effectively inseparable r.e. sets $A$ and $B$, and include axioms that force $R_{k}(c)$ to hold if $k \in A$ and $\lnot R_{k}(c)$ to hold if $k \in B$.  This is an r.e. set of axioms, and so by standard results there is a computable set of axioms in the same language that generates the same theory. If we had a computable model, the set of $k$ in which $R_k(c)$ holds would be a computable separating set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We show informally that there is an algorithm which will decide, on input a sentence $\varphi$ of our language, whether or not $\varphi$ is a theorem of $T$. We will **assume** that $T$ is finitely axiomatized.

By the Completeness Theorem, $\varphi$ is a theorem of $T$ if and only if $\varphi$ is true in all models of $T$.  Algorithm $1$ checks, one by one, all $L$-structures with underlying set $\{1,2,3,\dots\}$, searching for one which is a model of $T$ and in which $\varphi$ is false.

Simultaneously, Algorithm $2$ lists, in alphabetical order, all proofs in $T$ of length $1,2,3,4,\dots$, and checks for each such proof whether $\varphi$ is the last sentence of the proof.

One of Algorithm $1$ or $2$ must terminate, and therefore we have a decision procedure for whether or not $\varphi$ is a theorem of $T$.

For the second problem, note that any model of $T^\ast$ is a model of $T$, and therefore has cardinality $\le n(T)$.

Comment: It should be possible to just exhaustively check all models of size no more than $n(T)$, right, and then see if some statement is true in all ones that satisfy $T$?

Comment: @CarlMummert: I don't quite see that. If $n(T)$ is **known**, then we certainly can. If we merely know that there exists such an $n(T)$, then we do not know when to stop. That's why the fancier version.

Comment: To prove that $T$ is decidable, we only need to show some algorithm decides it, and we can hard code $n(T)$ into that algorithm. This is a triviality in the definitions that is often useful when we only need to know the value of a finite number of parameters in order to make an algorithm: if they tell me that an $n(T)$ exists, I will tell them that an algorithm exists in the same sense that $n(T)$ does.

Comment: This answer does give something else, though. It we assume that $T$ is finitely axiomatized and that whenever $T + \phi$ is consistent then $T + \phi$ has a finite model, then this method gives an algorithm for deciding $T$, even without assuming there is a bound on the size of the finite models. Very interesting!

Comment: Many thanks for all your responses. I was wondering whether those formalized theories that -if consistent - are incomplete by Gödel's First Incompleteness Theorem can ever have finite models. Or must they only have infinite models? It seems that the latter is the case.

Comment: @GarabedGulbenkian: You might want to ask this as separate question. My guess (but I have not written out the details) is that we can take a finitely axiomatized theory in which all recursive functions are representable, and alter it so that it has a singleton model but the rest are unchanged. I think we can set things up so that in the modified theory all recursive functions are representable.

Comment: Any theory that has arbitrarily large finite models must also have an infinite model. Perhaps some theory of that sort might do the job.